# Switching from HTTP to HTTPS in a Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, https

I am building a FLEX web application that also has a payment module where the user needs to enter his credit card details.

The whole Flex application runs on HTTP. However, whenever the user lands on a page where we ask for credit card details, we want these details to be sent over HTTPS.
In this page we need information from the model of the application, because it holds certain selection the user did, the state the application is in, etc.

How can I best solve this? 
Do I need to make this page a Module that runs on HTTPS?
Or can I just configure the specific 'credit card' services (we have a JAVA back end) so that these run on HTTPS?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will run into issues with the browser's same-orgin policy when you try to make requests to https://foo.com from an application loaded from http://foo.com.  I'd recommend just putting the application and services on https.  However if you do that make sure you are using the Flex Framework RSLs because most browsers don't cache SWFs loaded over https.

Comment: Ok thanks. So that means the complete application runs over HTTPS right? 
I believe I can do that without a problem. 
Do you know any consequences running the whole thing over HTTPS, will it affect performance for example?

Comment: Yeah.  Load the application over https and only make requests via https.  There will be a very minor performance hit on the server.